# Error trying to copy contents of editText from one to the other

Tags: android, android-edittext

```
class clicker implements Button.OnClickListener
        {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {                        
                    if(v==button1)
                    {
                        text1.setText(myChoice);
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 

                            "~~~~Successfully submitted~~~", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                       if(v==button2)
                    {
                        /*Intent viewDataIntent = new Intent(SurveyActivity.this, Survey2.class);
                        String myData = "You should see this";
                        viewDataIntent.putExtra("valueOne", myData);
                        startActivity(viewDataIntent);
                        */

                           text2.setText(text1.getText());

                           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 

                                   text1.getText(), 
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
        }
```

In the above program, there are two editText boxes text1 and text2; I am trying to copy the contents of text1 to text2. I tried doing `text2.setText(text1.getText());` but does not work.  Any ideas?

Comment: when i press button 2 i get an error saying the program has stopped. Most probably because of this line text2.setText(text1.getText());

Comment: just need to know how you copy the contents of one edit Text to the other....

Comment: 02-27 14:13:32.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1051): java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: see my answer and check its wors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

`text2.setText(text1.getText().toString());`

Answer (score 1):

```
    if(text1.length()!=0){
    text2.setText(text1.getText());
}
```